# Error 0x84BB0001 while installing Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am receiving the 0x84BB0001 Error after attempting to install a new instance of SQL Server 2012.  This is happening after an uninstall of a previous version of SQL Server 2012.  I have pasted the log file below.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068119551
  Exit facility code:            1211
  Exit error code:               1
  Exit message:                  The system cannot find the file specified.  
  Start time:                    2014-07-29 11:59:09
  End time:                      2014-07-29 12:09:12
  Requested action:              Install
  Exception help link:           http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=0x37D77D9E%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0x37D77D9E%400xDC80C325

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for Replication:     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for SSMS:            SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for SNAC:            SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for SNAC_SDK:        SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for LocalDB:         SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for Writer:          SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for Browser:         SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  MAPCOM444
  Machine processor count:       4
  OS version:                    Windows 7
  OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2012
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       11
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         c:\a95a4ef80214055fe53d\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Express

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    true
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                false
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, SSMS, SNAC_SDK, LOCALDB
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    SQLEXPRESS
  INSTANCENAME:                  SQLEXPRESS
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20140729_114734\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       LocalDB
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20140729_114734\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException
    Message: 
        The system cannot find the file specified.

    HResult : 0x84bb0001
        FacilityCode : 1211 (4bb)
        ErrorCode : 1 (0001)
    Data: 
      WatsonData = SQLBrowser
      DisableRetry = true
      HelpLink.EvtType = 0x37D77D9E@0xDC80C325
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack: 
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.Service.GetStartAccount()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlBrowser.SqlBrowserPublicConfig.CalculateUserNamePassword()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlBrowser.SqlBrowserPublicConfig.Calculate()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateSettings(IEnumerable`1 settingIds)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Settings.Calculate()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.InstallWizardFramework.ConfigurationController.LoadData()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.InstallWizard.ServicesController.LoadData()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.InstallWizardFramework.InstallWizardPageHost.PageEntered(PageChangeReason reason)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.InstallWizardFramework.InstallWizardTabbedPageHost.PageEntered(PageChangeReason reason)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.WizardFramework.UIHost.set_SelectedPageIndex(Int32 value)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.InstallWizardFramework.ConfigurationController.OnPageNavigationRequest(PageChangeReason reason)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.InstallWizard.DiskUsageController.LoadData()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.InstallWizardFramework.InstallWizardPageHost.PageEntered(PageChangeReason reason)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.WizardFramework.UIHost.set_SelectedPageIndex(Int32 value)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.WizardFramework.NavigationButtons.nextButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
    Inner exception type: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
        Message: 
                The system cannot find the file specified.

        HResult : 0x80004005
        Error : 2
        Stack: 
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.Service.QueryServiceConfig()
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.Service.GetStartAccount()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get past the error by changing the instance name.  The old instance name from the uninstalled version was SQLEXPRESS, I changed this to SQLEXPRESS2012 and the installation proceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling isn't always enough when it comes to MS dev products, try running a discovery report:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samlester/archive/2013/06/13/sql-server-2012-discovery-report-determining-what-sql-server-components-are-installed.aspx

Your error specifically focuses around :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqljourney/archive/2012/05/07/sql-2008-2008-r2-setup-disappears-fails-when-installing-setup-support-files.aspx

I wouldn't go that far though, uninstall using the sql uninstaller & then eyeball program files for left over sql entries and remove those.  That's worked best for me in the past without having to mess w the registry.

Comment: The discovery report indicated that there is nothing installed on the machine.  On the original uninstall I removed all SQL programs and features using Control Panel -> Uninstall, removed related registry entries, and renamed existed Program Files and Program Files (x86) SQL-related folders.  I am attempting the re-install using the SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU installer from Microsoft.

Comment: If you did all that correctly as you claim it should've worked.  You have an error code though & link #2 specifically addresses that error code.  At minimum you should have a new error code to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the contents in the folder?

C:/Users/[UserName]/AppData/Local/Microsoft_Corporation.

installation again as a repair, hope this will work.

Comment: This was one of the steps I took in the original uninstall.  Thank you though.